# Fill 2D array in C from text file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, text-files

I have a text file which provides the input data for creating a communications network between cities.

```
N=12

C=[72,107,65,99,20,11,31,7,42,28,4, 31,10,57,37,71,18,17,73,39,14, 91,77,19,39,33,59,31,44,98, 71,66,36,23,10,100,93,41, 21,80,22,43,78,22,93, 77,81,49,62,89,19, 21,19,51,40,18, 102,92,28,51, 31,47,51, 73,38, 50]

R=[0.81,0.88,0.83,0.90,0.98,0.93,0.86,0.91,0.92,0.86,0.80, 0.91,0.87,0.78,0.83,0.90,0.93,0.87,0.79,0.99,0.94, 0.88,0.98,0.97,0.96,0.92,0.81,0.99,0.92,0.91, 0.80,0.88,0.87,0.93,0.90,0.99,0.98,0.91, 0.89,0.80,0.92,0.93,0.83,0.87,0.99, 0.97,0.91,0.89,0.99,0.94,0.90, 0.87,0.89,0.95,0.85,0.96, 0.99,0.79,0.88,0.81, 0.84,0.97,0.77, 0.83,0.93, 0.99]

a_b=1

Req_Reliability =  0.5

Req_Cost = 267
```

Where: 
**N** is the number of cities in the network
 and **C** & **R** the symmetric N by N matrices giving respectively the cost and reliability of implementing a connection between two cities.

**N** can vary, as long as it is an integer above 2. And the given matrices C & R will vary accordingly.

From the text file, since the matrices are symmetric, only the upper half of the matrices are given and all elements with indexes i=j should be 0, such that matrix C's format in the text file is as such:

```
C=[C(1-2),C(1-3),...,C(1-12),whitespaceC(2-3),C(2-4),...,C(2-12),...,whitespaceC(11-12)]
with C(IDstartCity-IDstopCity)
```

The whitespace in the text file denotes a change to a lower row, and the same structure applies to matrix R.

What I want to do is assign each variable to its match in my C program.
While I have an idea on how to assign 12 to N, I am clueless as to how I could assign the strange structuring of matrices C and R from the text file to the ones in the C program.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    FILE *finput;
    char var_name[5];
    int value = 0;
    finput = fopen("Prj1_input.txt", "r");

    //Inputs Start
    int N;                              //Number of cities
        //Cost Array
    int **C = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        C[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        memset(C[i], 0, N * sizeof(int));
    }

    //Reliability Array
    double **R = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        R[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
        memset(R[i], 0, N * sizeof(double));
    }
    int con_cost;                       //Connection cost between 2 cities
    double con_reliability;             //Connection reliability between 2 cities

    int a_b;                            //0 is type a, 1 is type b

    double Req_reliability, Req_cost;   //reliability for type a, cost for type b
    //Inputs Stop


    fscanf(finput, "%c=%d", var_name, &value);

    printf("%s %d\n", var_name, value);



    fclose(finput);

    return 0;
}
```

I suppose that I could use two for-loops, where when I find a white space in the text file, I increment the row, but I have absolutely no idea how to deal with the text file.

For now, provided I comment out everything between //input start and //input stop, the output is
    N 12

Thanks

Comment: `int N; double C[N][N], R[N][N];` not legal in C you can not use variables to specify the size of an array in C. Look into the `malloc` built in function located in `stdlib.h` in order to dynamically allocate arrays

Comment: Thanks, they were more of placeholders, I am more interested in how to deal with reading the input text file. (I am gonna edit the question though)

Comment: show content of the text file just as it exists.  That will direct how it is parsed.

Comment: @ryyker The text file is exactly as it exists, each variable = value is on one line, and the specific formatting for the arrays is explained.

Comment: Is the design of the text file (format) set in concrete, or changeable?  Again, small changes in its format can simplify parsing.

Comment: Yes, but only minor changes

Answer (score 0):

Take C as an example, make an array of arrays of size N first:

```
int **C = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    C[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    memset(C[i], 0, N * sizeof(int));
}
```

Then loop and assign to the matrix:

```
char *s = "<the string inside the [...]>";
char *p = s, *e;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        e = strchr(p, ',');
        *e = '\0';
        C[i][j] = atoi(p);
        p = e + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: R is similar except that convert it to double.

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify how the code in the matrix assignment works?What are e and p?

Comment: So when you get the string inside the bracket, it is merely a comma separated string, you can keep searching for the comma, and feed the found token to atoi to convert to integer. One caveat is that atoi accepts null terminated string, so you need to change the comma to null before feed to atoi.

Comment: So of course you could use strtok for this job, I just find strchr simpler ;)

Comment: okay, it's a bit clearer. How is the white space dealt with though?

Comment: It works because of atoi, it ignores the leading spaces

Comment: I see, I'll have to slightly change the forloops then, as the input matrix C from the text file is not a 12x12, it's rather the top right portion of a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Yes, note the inner loop starts from i + 1

Comment: Okay thanks, and final question, to obtain the string between [..] should I do something of the sort? `fscanf(finput, "%c=[%c]", var_name, values);` and if so how big should I set values? 'char values = sizeOfStringArray'

Comment: If the format is fixed, you can just strip the begin part, that will be much simpler. Suppose char *line = "the whole line"; then char* s = line + 3; s will be fight the string needed here.

Comment: The ending ] can be ignored as it will be ignored be convention.

Comment: if `strtok()` is successful, it will null terminate its output.  You do not need to do anything more than just check that the output buffer is not NULL.

Comment: as I said, strtok works of course, it is just too nasty for newcomers of C.

Comment: I am getting 11 segmentation faults when running the code, any idea where that might come from?

Comment: Please paste your actual code, I will see what's wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you describe it is parsing. Your text files is made up of lines, each having unique searchable content.  This should help you to identify each line, then set up the unique parsing rules for each.  `strtok()` will work well for most of the lines, with the exception of C and R.  See comments for explanation. The following template is enough to get you started. The real value of this code will be if you step through it in a debugger to see how `fgets(), strtok(), atoi()` work together.  It also points out some illegal pre-existing syntax, corrected:

```
//procedure and function prototype
//int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) { //illegal main declaration
int main(int argc,  char * argv[]) {

    FILE *finput;
    char var_name[5];
    int value = 0;
    char line[280];//adjust size as needed for longer content
    int N;                              //Number of cities
    char *tok;
    int i;//previously undeclared

    finput = fopen(".\\Prj1_input.txt", "r");
    if(finput)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 280, finput))
        {
            if(strstr (line, "N=")) //get N and create memory for arrays
            {
                tok = strtok(line, "N=\n \t");
                if(tok)//if no output, leave
                {
                    N = atoi(tok);//read about error checking for this function
                                  //in your final code you should check output for
                                  //LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN and check errno
                    double **C = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));

                    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
                    {
                        C[i] = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
                    }
                    double **R = (double **)malloc(N * sizeof(double *));

                    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
                        R[i] = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(strstr (line, "C=[")) //get C array elements
            {
                //because of the combination of comma and space delimiter
                //and the fact that the count of numbers before a space is not constant
                //between numbers, strtok is not the best way to parse this 
            }
            if(strstr (line, "R=[")) //get R array elements
            {
                //same as above comment
            }
            if(strstr (line, "a_b=")) //get a_b value
            {
                //similar to parsing N
            }
            if(strstr (line, "Req_Reliability")) //get Req_Reliability
            {
                //similar to parsing N
            }
            if(strstr (line, "Req_Cost"))  //get Req_Cost
            {
                //similar to parsing N
            }
        }
        fclose(finput);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do not forget to free all the memory (more than 2Kbytes) you have created.

For C and R arrays, given your delimiter and other criteria you may have to loop through the string 1 character at a time to identify numbers as you find them, storing them in yet another intermediate buffer, and convert using `atoi()` between commas, then increment an index for each space you come upon to start the next row.

Comment: That's a great template to work with, I will try to merge it with fluter's answer. Thanks! I am guessing that I should add "=" after Req_Reliability and Req_Cost in the if statements

Comment: @darkf222 - Not necessarily.  `strstr()` is just checking for a sub-string.  In this case it will pass the test with only what I have.  I have run the code, it goes into all 6 conditions successfully.  And keep in mind, if you can change the content (format) of your input file to make parsing easier, I would do it.  For example get rid of the spaces. ( I am not sure exactly what _The whitespace in the text file denotes a change to a lower row_ means, but because it adds in with the other criteria you mention, it will likely make parsing using `strtok(), etc. impossible )

Comment: Oh I see, I was not familiar with `strstr()`, and is it correct to do: `fscanf(finput, "%c=[%c]", var_name, arr_values);` to obtain the string `arr_values` between the `[]` for matrix C and R?

Comment: @darkf222 - There is lots written about format specifiers for `(f)scanf()`.  _[Here is one](http://www.mobidev.com/shalan/scanf_printf.htm)_.  The one you asked about, although it may read values, it is not a viable choice for getting all of your data into the arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I am rather unfamiliar with io with text files and strings, I'll read up on it!